# How to save data from many PC to one table SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want to save some data to one table from many PC. But the data have a index(ID) that fill manually and order from previous data(ID), so I check it first on database then increment it.The problem is If more than one PC/device save together, it will save with same result. How to solve this problem?

This is query for search the last ID that used:

```
> public DataRow GetPlayerIDByClient(object clientPK)
>         {
>             DataRow result = null;
>  
>             if (clientPK != null)
>             {
>                 IDbDataParameter clientFKParam = this.CreateParameter(csPlayerNamesEntity.Names.ClientFK, clientPK);
>  
>                 string selectCommand = string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM {0} WHERE {1} = {3} AND " +
>                                                         "({2} LIKE 'G%' or {2} LIKE 'g%') ORDER BY {4} DESC",
>                                                         csPlayerNamesEntity.Names.TableName, //0
>                                                         csPlayerNamesEntity.Names.ClientFK, //1
>                                                         csPlayerNamesEntity.Names.ID,//2
>                                                         clientFKParam,//3
>                                                         csPlayerNamesEntity.Names.PK); //4
>  
>                 DataTable dt = this.ExecReaderDataTable(selectCommand, clientFKParam);
>  
>                 if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
>                 {
>                     result = dt.Rows[0];
>                 }
>             }
>  
>             return result;
>         }
```

Comment: Did you hear about Entity Framework? It will make your life much easier when dealing with databases in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: It is a design problem. You have multiple possible solutions. You could synchronize your clients from a central instance. Or better write the data into an import table and let a job on the database transfer the imported data to the production table.

Comment: SQL Server gives you the solutions to this problem. For example, you can use and identity column (autoincremental) for the ID column, or you can use sequences to retrieve the next ID. Google for SQL Server Sequence.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table updating from multiple sources and you need to ensure that the ID is set correctly there are two solutions that are fairly common.

One is to make the primary key an identity column which increments on SQL Server itself. If you need this value back in SQL Server, you can construct your INSERT SQL with a SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() at the end so you get the Id back to your application. Two programs/machines inserting stuff will be marshalled by SQL Server and you won't get overlapping IDs.

The other way is to make the column a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER and supply a Guid from your application. Since they are unique regardless of source they different machines/processes won't clash. However, there can be a performance penalty on large tables as the Ids won't be sequential and it will fragment the table as SQL Server has to shuffle rows around when inserting to make room for a row in the correct sequence.